# Processing numbers program

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Firstly, I'm taking AP Computer Science this year, and this question is related to an exercise we were assigned in class. I have written the code, and verified that it meets the requirements to my knowledge, so this is *not* a topic searching for homework answers.

What I'm looking for is to see if there's a much simpler way to do this, or if there's anything I could improve on in writing my code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated, specific questions asked below the code.

The exercise is as follows: Write a program called ProcessingNumbers that does:

- Accepts a user input as a string of numbers
- Prints the smallest and largest of all the numbers supplied by the user
- Print the sum of all the even numbers the user typed, along with the largest even number typed.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ProcessingNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize variables and objects
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
        int sumOfEven = 0;

        // Initial input
        System.out.print("Please input 10 integers, separated by spaces.");

        // Stores 10 values from the scanner in the ArrayList
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            al.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        // Sorts in ascending order
        Collections.sort(al);

        // Smallest and largest values section
        int smallest = al.get(0);
        int largest = al.get(al.size() - 1);
        System.out.println("Your smallest value is " + smallest + " and your largest value is " + largest);

        // Sum of Even numbers
        int arrayLength = al.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            if (al.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                sumOfEven += al.get(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of all even numbers is " + sumOfEven);

        // Last section, greatest even number 
        if (al.get(arrayLength - 1) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The greatest even number typed is " + al.get(arrayLength - 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("The greatest even number typed is " + al.get(arrayLength - 2));
        }


        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Here are specific questions I'd like answered, if possible:

1. Did I overthink this? Was there a much simpler, more streamlined way to solve the problem?
2. Was the use of an ArrayList mostly necessary? We haven't learned about them yet, I did get approval from my teacher to use them though.
3. How could I possibly code it so that there is no 10 integer limit?

This is my first time on Stackoverflow in quite some time, so let me know if anything's out of order.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "The greatest even number typed is 9" Well I didn't know 9 was even!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Heh, I didn't exactly test this with a lot of cases, moreso finished it up and posted this as a break. What set of numbers were entered for this to occur? Edit: Found the problem, working on fixing it.

Comment: Andreas, thanks, will post it there.

Comment: @Andreas I entered `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9`

Comment: *"Accepts a user input as a string of numbers".* To me, that means a single line of text, with as few or as many numbers as the user sees fit. Not 10.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it does. The teacher said for this purpose the exercise was more about collaborating with another programmer and code readability, so he said we could do it like that after a few of us asked. What I'm wondering is what'd be the best way to eliminate that requirement? I tried something like while (sc.hasNext()) { // code } but found that ended in me typing in an endless amount of integers into the console, hah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of the ArrayList wasn't necessary, however it does make it much simpler due to `Collections.sort()`.

To remove the 10 integer limit you can ask the user how many numbers they want to enter:

```
int numbersToEnter = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < numbersToEnter; i++) {
    al.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Another note is that your last if-else to get the highest even integer doesn't work, you want to use a for loop, something like this:

```
for (int i = al.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (al.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("The greatest even number typed is " + al.get(i));
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I wouldn't say so. Your code is pretty straightforward and simple. You could break it up into separate methods to make it cleaner and more organized, though that isn't necessary unless you have sections of code that have to be run repeatedly or if you have long sections of code cluttering up your main method. You also could have just used `al.size()` instead of creating `arrayLength`.
2. It wasn't entirely necessary, though it is convenient. Now, regarding your next question, you definitely do want to use an `ArrayList` rather than a regular array if you want it to have a variable size, since arrays are created with a fixed size which can't be changed.
3. Here's an example:

   ```
   int number;
   System.out.print("Please input some integers, separated by spaces, followed by -1.");

   number = sc.nextInt();
   while (number != -1) {
       al.add(number);
       number = sc.nextInt();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I've got some good practice stuff to work on like breaking it up into methods, but just wanted to get this done quickly, not exactly sure why I didn't just use al.size() though.

Comment: Didn't even think of using some sort of terminator for the input, either. Will definitely implement that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that:

- Doesn't use `Scanner` (it's a heavyweight when all you need is a line of text)
- Doesn't have a strict limit to the number of numbers
- Doesn't need to ask how many numbers
- Doesn't waste space/time on a `List`
- Handles the case when no numbers are entered
- Handles the case when no even numbers are entered
- Fails with `NumberFormatException` if non-integer is entered
- Moved actual logic to separate method, so it can be mass tested

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Enter numbers, separated by spaces:");
    processNumbers(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
}
public static void processNumbers(String numbers) {
    int min = 0, max = 0, sumOfEven = 0, maxEven = 1, count = 0;
    if (! numbers.trim().isEmpty())
        for (String value : numbers.trim().split("\\s+")) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
            if (count++ == 0)
                min = max = number;
            else if (number < min)
                min = number;
            else if (number > max)
                max = number;
            if ((number & 1) == 0) {
                sumOfEven += number;
                if (maxEven == 1 || number > maxEven)
                    maxEven = number;
            }
        }
    if (count == 0)
        System.out.println("No numbers entered");
    else {
        System.out.println("Smallest number: " + min);
        System.out.println("Largest number: " + max);
        if (maxEven == 1)
            System.out.println("No even numbers entered");
        else {
            System.out.println("Sum of even numbers: " + sumOfEven);
            System.out.println("Largest even number: " + maxEven);
        }
    }
}
```

*Tests*

```
Enter numbers, separated by spaces:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9
Smallest number: 1
Largest number: 9
Sum of even numbers: 20
Largest even number: 8
```

```
Enter numbers, separated by spaces:
1 3 5 7 9
Smallest number: 1
Largest number: 9
No even numbers entered
```

```
Enter numbers, separated by spaces:
-9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4
Smallest number: -9
Largest number: -4
Sum of even numbers: -18
Largest even number: -4
```

```
Enter numbers, separated by spaces:

No numbers entered
```

Comment: Thanks! A bit over my head at this point, but I'll definitely look at it more in depth whenever I have time to. Much appreciated!